# Can't figure out Scalar Variable Error when Altering Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, alter

I have an existing sql server stored procedure, that I'm trying to update.  Every time I run Alter Procedure on it, I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@varOne".
```

I've Googled around but nothing that I can find helps out with how to get past this error... :/  Procedure below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test] (
  -- Declare
  @varOne tinyint,
  @varTwo numeric(17,0)
) As

Set NoCount On
-- Select
Select  *
Into    #t
From    SQL_Test.dbo.trans with (nolock)
Where   test>=123
    And Case @varOne When 1 Then rNo  When 2 Then iNo  When 3 Then sNo End = @varTwo

Union
Select  *
From    SQL_Test.dbo.trsave with (nolock)
Where   date_time > DateAdd(dd, -60, GetDate())
    And Case @varOne When 1 Then rNo  When 2 Then iNo  When 3 Then sNo End = @varTwo
```

EDIT: I solved the problem by dropping the original procedure, and recreating it.  Still curious why the alter would not work.  Guessing it is caused by the client using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Side notes: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) & [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) (tl;dr yes).

Comment: Also, can't repro: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=180be16489890e28e2e314feef1d6cba).

Comment: No idea about the bad habits.  I'm just trying to edit the existing procedure, and I run into that error every time I try to alter it.

Comment: The bad habits are for you to read and understand. As for the error, as I mentioned, I can't repro it; that statement does not produce the error.

Comment: I can't reproduce either. There must be something else going on. Can you try doing the alter statement in a brand new query tab? Delete the comment that says -- Declare just to be safe the engine is not misinterpreting it?
Also, what version of SQL Server are you using? Try select @@Version

Comment: Yeah, tried deleting the --declare, with the same results.  Looking at the SQL version could be the issue, for sure.  They are using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3156.0 (X64).  Oddly enough, I tried just dropping the existing one and recreating, and that worked.  So, something odd about that SQL Server, and the altering... ?

Comment: Seems that way. Glad you could work around the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by dropping the original procedure, and recreating it. Still curious why the alter would not work. Guessing it is caused by the client using SQL Server 2012.